# How to Encrypt data to a Plain text without Special character in java

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I need a encryption algorithm by whick I can encrypt the data to a simple plain text.

Currently i am using **AES**  **encrypting algorithm** which converts to encrypt string contains Special character.

Here if i send this string through a query string in url I am missing some character like- "+".

So i need a encrypt logic which is secure and contains only alphabet.

Here is my encryption logic :

```
      public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }
```

Here I am getting an encrypted String  "**TEj+TWBQExpz8/p5SAjIhA==**"

while I am sending through query string as

**localhost:8080/myproject/home?code=TEj+TWBQExpz8/p5SAjIhA==**

i am getting the String in **controller** as-
"**TEj TWBQExpz8/p5SAjIhA==**"

"+" symbol is missing thats why i am getting issue while decryption.

Please suggest any new Algorithm or any solution to avoid the Special character.

Thank you.

Comment: *...send this string through a query string...*  What does it mean?

Comment: IMO, special characters make encryption stronger. Any special reason why you want t avoid them? Why don't you write a simple encryption algorithm which will work for you?

Comment: you just need to URL-encode the result

Comment: Hi @akhil_mittal . I know that it is secure. Can you please suggest me how i can pass it from web url so that i will get all the character and it wont generate the exception.

Comment: @Thilo can you suggest me an example.

Answer (score 6):

You can encode your crypted part with URLEncoder

```
URLEncoder.encode("TEj+TWBQExpz8/p5SAjIhA==", "UTF-8")
```

to make it valid for the URL.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Answer (score 4):

You should try Apache Commons [Base64 URL safe encoder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafe(byte[])), which will generate what you need.

Hope it helps,

Jose Luis

Comment: that is encoding, not encrypting

Comment: The question was how to URL Safe encode encrypted data, not how to encrypt it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `URLEncoder` to encode the encrypted value, before sending it through URL.

and at decryption side, you have to use `URLDecoder` first to decode received data.

You can do following in your code to achieve this :

```
public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);

        String urlEncodeddata=URLEncoder.encode(encryptedValue,"UTF-8");
        return urlEncodeddata;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        String urlDecodedData=URLDecoder.decode(encryptedData, "UTF-8");
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(urlDecodedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @sachin I am getting exception at c.doFinal(decodeValue); How can I resolve that ?

Comment: what is the exception you are getting ?

Comment: sorry, this time i am getting exception like  Bad padding Exception by removing the URLDecoder.decode()   it is working fine.
Sending the value as URL encoder String but while I am getting the value from request paramenter those are still special character.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue in Spring based application and I solved the problem with Base64 Encoding/Decoding process.

Encoding:

```
String encryptedString = encrypt(stringData);
byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptedString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String base64Encoded = new String(encoded);
```

Decoding:

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Encoded.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String encryptedString = new String(decoded);
```

Than you can successfully decrypt "encryptedString" value on your decrypt method.

```
String decryptedString = decrypt(encryptedString);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I agree with this answer. You can encode the encrypted text like "TEj TWBQExpz8/p5SAjIhA==" to base64. Then you just need to decode the base64 string before decrypting your encrypted text.

Answer (score 0):

Use only `URLEncode` no need to change code.

`String encodedStr = URLEncoder.encode(encrypt("XYZ"), "UTF-8");`

And there is no need to use URLDecode for decoding url as you can use normal
`decrypt(encodedStr);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this in C# Application  to encode the encrypted value, before sending it through URL.
Decryption side, you have to use UrlDecode first to decode QueryString data.

```
 Server.UrlEncode("");
 Server.UrlDecode("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString.

Example:

```
  private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
  private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";
  private static final String ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString();

  @Value("${vector}")
  private String vector;

  @Value("${key}")
  private String key;

  public String encrypt(String value) {
    try {
      Cipher cipher = initCipher(ENCRYPT_MODE);
      byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
      return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(encrypted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  public String decrypt(String encrypted) {
    try {
      Cipher cipher = initCipher(DECRYPT_MODE);
      byte[] originalText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted));
      return new String(originalText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  private Cipher initCipher(int mode) throws Exception {
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(vector.getBytes(ENCODING));
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(ENCODING), ALGORITHM);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
    cipher.init(mode, skeySpec, iv);
    return cipher;
  }
```

Comment: Kindly edit your answer and append the ENCODING to "cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes()" and "return new String(originalText);" as you already did for IV and KEY conversion, thanks.